# Deserialize JSON with dictionary as attribute results in null .NET Dictionary<string,string>

Tags: .net, json, serialization, dictionary

I have a WCF web service method defined where one of the parameters `dict` is a `Dictionary<string,string>`:

```
public Models.ActEntry Create(string userName, int codeNo, int typeNo, int relatedPkey, DateTime createTime, string info, Dictionary<string, string> dict)
```

The JSON being supplied to IIS is below (NOTE: The value for sUser is supplied by the authentication layer):

```
{"codeNo":100,"typeNo":1,"relatedPkey":269222839,"createTime":"\/Date(1416002315864)\/","info":"something","dict":{"one":"first","two":"second","three":"third"}}
```

The JSON is happily deserialized without error but the value of `dict` is null (`Count = 0`).  All the other attributes are deserialized properly.  I can clearly see in the trace logs that IIS recognizes `dict` and correctly types it as an object but when I look at the `Dictionary<string,string>` variable `dict` in the method, it is null.

```
[HttpRequest] Method            POST
[HttpRequest] Content-Length    161
[HttpRequest] Content-Type      application/json; charset=utf-8
[HttpRequest] Authorization     Basic ZHNcYmFybmVzcjpSZWN0MWYxZXI=
[HttpRequest] Expect            100-continue
[HttpRequest] Host              **************
[HttpRequest] X-FECTransaction  63dc8855-e55d-48b0-b31b-ec44ea52b56e
[root] [root] type              object
[root] [codeNo] type            number
[root] codeNo                   100
[root] [typeNo] type            number
[root] typeNo                   1
[root] [relatedPkey] type       number
[root] relatedPkey              269222839
[root] [info] type              string
[root] info                     something
[root] [createTime] type        string
[root] createTime               /Date(1416002315864)/
[root] [dict] type              object
[root] [one] type               string 
[root] one                      first 
[root] [two] type               string
[root] two                      second 
[root] [three] type             string 
[root] three                    third
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done in the DataContract Serializer. Maybe you can use it:
Add to DataContract-class DataMember attribute. Then use KnownType attributes for expected types used for object. in the following example I use either int or bool in the collection :

```
[DataContract]
    [KnownType(typeof(int[]))]
    [KnownType(typeof(bool[]))]
    public class CompositeType
    {
        [DataMember]
        public object UsedForKnownTypeSerializationObject;

    [DataMember]
    public string StringValue
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [DataMember]
    public Dictionary<string, object> Parameters
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Comment: From your response, I found this page [Data Contract Known Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167(v=vs.110).aspx) which seems to support your proposal.  I've not time to test this out right now but it appears like a valid approach.  Given that, I'll mark yours as the answer until someone proves otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Providing this for future reference: According to the paragraph below (from [Stand-Alone JSON Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412170.aspx)), it appears WCF cannot directly deserialize a Dictionary<>:

> Dictionaries are not a way to work directly with JSON.
>   Dictionary may not be supported in the same way in WCF
>   as expected from working with other JSON technologies. For example, if
>   "abc" is mapped to "xyz" and "def" is mapped to 42 in a dictionary,
>   the JSON representation is not {"abc":"xyz","def":42} but is
>   [{"Key":"abc","Value":"xyz"},{"Key":"def","Value":42}] instead.

I confirmed that the .Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer handles dictionaries just fine.  But the deserializer in WCF does not.  Not sure why -- or why this has never been addressed -- but there you are.  I found several articles with implementation of alternative deserializers but chose not to go that route.